# There are 3 machines, what is the probability that the one I pick is working?

Tags: probability

There are 3 machines, machines 1,2 and 3.

The probability that they're working when turned on is shown below:

```
P(1) = 0.9
P(2) = 0.8
P(3) = 0.4
```

If I pick one machine at random from those 3, what is the probability that that one is working?

Clearly `P` for picking any machine in particular is `1/3`

The solution in the book is `.7`, which is `P(1)+P(2)+P(3)/3`.

It 'makes sense' to me that the solution would look something like that but I really do not understand where that came from.

How do you arrive at that using Kolmogorovs axioms (along with derived theorems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). The law of total probability is the proposition that if $\left\{{B_n : n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots}\right\}$ is a finite or countably infinite partition of a sample space (in other words, a set of pairwise disjoint events whose union is the entire sample space) and each event $B_n$ is measurable, then for any event $A$ of the same probability space
$$
\Pr(A)=\sum_n \Pr(A\cap B_n)
$$
or, alternatively,
$$
\Pr(A)=\sum_n \Pr(A\mid B_n)\Pr(B_n),
$$
where, for any $n$, for which $\Pr(B_n) = 0$, these terms are simply omitted from the summation, because $\Pr(A\mid B_n)$, is finite.

In this particular case
$$
\Pr\{\text{the picked machine is working}\}=0.9\cdot\frac13+0.8\cdot\frac13+0.4\cdot\frac13=0.7.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ denote the event that you picked machine $i$ and let $A$ denote the event that the picked machine works. Then
$$
P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}P(A ; X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}P(A \mid X_i)P(X_i) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}P(A \mid X_i).
$$
We used the law of total expectation here.